# trello api "PUT /1/cards/[card id]/desc" returns a 400 response with message "invalid value for value"

Tags: java, api, trello

I've spend a week trying to work out how to update some card information, I'd hoped to update a load of fields at one, e.g. name, desc, idList, closed etc, but after looking around it seems they have to be done individually, but when I try I keep getting a 400 response with message "invalid value for value" .

e.g. When I try to 
PUT https://api.trello.com/1/cards/[cardid]/desc?key=[mykey]&token=[mytoken]value=just+yet+another+test+of+trello+side+extended

what am I doing wrong?

Java code used to send Put is

```
private static InputStream doRequest(final String url, final String requestMethod, final Map<String, String> map) 
{
    try 
    {
        final HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url)
                .openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        conn.setDoOutput(requestMethod.equals(METHOD_POST) || requestMethod.equals(METHOD_PUT));
        conn.setRequestMethod(requestMethod);

        String plus = "";
        if (map != null && !map.isEmpty()) 
        {
            final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (String key : map.keySet()) 
            {
                sb.append(sb.length() > 0 ? "&" : "")
                    .append(key)
                    .append("=")
                    .append(URLEncoder.encode(map.get(key), "UTF-8"));
            }
            conn.getOutputStream().write(sb.toString().getBytes());
            conn.getOutputStream().close();
            plus = sb.toString();
        }
        final int rc = conn.getResponseCode();
        logger.info("response " + rc + " from " + requestMethod + " " + url + plus);
        if (rc > 399) 
        {
             return null;
        } 
        else 
        {
            return getWrappedInputStream(
                conn.getInputStream(), GZIP_ENCODING.equalsIgnoreCase(conn.getContentEncoding())
            );
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        throw new TrelloException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be helpful to know what the message is accompanying the 400.  Also, is there a reason you can't use https://trello.com/docs/api/card/index.html#put-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink to update multiple fields at once?

Comment: I've no idea how to get at the response message. And yea I have also tried using the one you said as well, but cant get that to work either.

Comment: What are you using to make the request?  Try `curl -i -X PUT https://api.trello.com/1/cards/[cardid]/desc?key=[mykey]&token=[mytoken]value=just+yet+another+test+of+trello+side+extended` and grab the output.  That should include the message.

Comment: I'm doing it from java. No idea what curl is

Comment: If you're on OS X or Linux, it is probably already installed, and you can paste that into a terminal.

Comment: What Java library are you using?  Can you put some code in your question?

Comment: It sounds like http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getResponseMessage() might get the response message.

Comment: response Message is just "Bad Request"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I was missing one line in the code

```
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

that solved the problem, so here is the complete code for doRequest now...

```
    private static InputStream doRequest(final String url, final String requestMethod, final Map<String, String> map) 
{
    try 
    {
        final HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        conn.setDoOutput(requestMethod.equals(METHOD_POST) || requestMethod.equals(METHOD_PUT));
        conn.setRequestMethod(requestMethod);
        // following line was missing and caused PUT not to work.
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        String arguments = "";
        if (map != null && !map.isEmpty()) 
        {
            final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (String key : map.keySet()) 
            {
                sb.append(sb.length() > 0 ? "&" : "");
                sb.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, HTTP_CHARACTER_ENCODING));
                sb.append("=");
                sb.append(URLEncoder.encode(map.get(key), HTTP_CHARACTER_ENCODING));
            }
            conn.getOutputStream().write(sb.toString().getBytes());
            conn.getOutputStream().close();
            arguments = sb.toString();
        }
        conn.connect();

        final int rc = conn.getResponseCode();
        final String responseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
        if (rc != 200)
            logger.info("response " + rc + " (" + responseMessage + ") from " + requestMethod + " " + url + " args:" + arguments);
        if (rc > 399) 
        {
            final String str = stream2String(conn.getErrorStream());
            logger.info("error response:" + str);
            return null;
        } 
        else 
        {
            return getWrappedInputStream(
                conn.getInputStream(), GZIP_ENCODING.equalsIgnoreCase(conn.getContentEncoding())
            );
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        throw new TrelloException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code:

```
sb.append(sb.length() > 0 ? "&" : "")
                .append(key)
                .append("=")
                .append(URLEncoder.encode(map.get(key), "UTF-8"));
```

It looks like you're actually building a url that looks like:

```
https://api.trello.com/1/cards/[cardid]/desc?key=[mykey]&token=[mytoken]value=just+yet+another+test+of+trello+side+extended
```

Note that there is no `&` between the `token` and `value` parameters.

Comment: The key and token are added to the url that's passed in

Comment: @user2790622 What is the output of the `logger.info` line?

Comment: response 400 (Bad Request) from PUT https://api.trello.com/1/cards/[cardid]/desc?key=[mykey]&token=[mytoken]value=just+yet+another+test+of+trello+side+extended

Comment: tried that (with and without the "&" before value), makes no difference

Comment: It sounds like there's something wrong with the library you're using.  "Bad Request" would only be the response if it wasn't properly-formatted http.  That means that this is a Java question, not a Trello question.

Comment: I've done a GET and POST no problems, so I'm stumped on where to look for an answer now.

Comment: That route works just fine, and there's nothing wrong with the URL you said you're using (other than the missing `&`), so there must be something you're not showing me.  We don't actually send a response of "Bad Request", so if you can find the actual response, that might be useful.

Comment: Just found out that there is a conn.getErrorStream(), using that It returns "invalid value for value"

Comment: @user2790622 The only restrictions on `value` is that it exist and be less than 16384 characters.